# Turning a string into a Uri in Android

Tags: java, android, uri

I have a string, `'songchoice'`. I want it to become a 'Uri' so I can use with `MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri)`

How can I convert songchoice to the Uri?

Answer (score 538, accepted):

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
```

Here's the doc http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Of course if there are any spaces in the string you pass in your app will barf all over the place if you launch an Intent with this Uri.

Comment: It shows cannot find symbole parse

Answer (score 9):

```
Uri.parse(STRING);
```

See doc:

> String: an RFC 2396-compliant, encoded URI

Url must be canonicalized before using, like this:

```
Uri.parse(Uri.decode(STRING));
```

Answer (score 2):

The String I had to convert to a URI was a local file path, but without the `file://` prefix. So even

```
 Uri.parse(Uri.decode(STRING));
```

resulted in `FileNotFoundException: No content provider` (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288619/what-to-do-when-java-io-filenotfoundexception-no-content-provider)).
I got a valid URI by first creating a `File` object i.e.:

```
Uri myUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(STRING));
```

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me.