# What to do when - java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider?

Tags: android, email, attachment, android-contentprovider

when I try to attach a file to an email, I get a java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider logcat output. 
If anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong or what I should do instead, that would be great.Thank you.

This is how I add the files to the email..:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                sendIntent.setType("video/3gp");
                sendIntent.setType("video/mp4");
                startActivity(sendIntent);
```

...and here is the entire logcat error output:

```
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168): IOException caught while opening or reading stream
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /sdcard/Video0006.mp4
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:507)
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:345)
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168):     at com.android.mms.model.MediaModel.initMediaSize(MediaModel.java:268)
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168):     at com.android.mms.model.MediaModel.<init>(MediaModel.java:76)
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168):     at com.android.mms.model.RegionMediaModel.<init>(RegionMediaModel.java:40)
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168):     at com.android.mms.model.VideoModel.<init>(VideoModel.java:55)
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168):     at com.android.mms.model.VideoModel.<init>(VideoModel.java:48)
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168):     at com.android.mms.data.WorkingMessage.changeMedia(WorkingMessage.java:434)
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168):     at com.android.mms.data.WorkingMessage.setAttachment(WorkingMessage.java:343)
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168):     at com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.addVideo(ComposeMessageActivity.java:2472)
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168):     at com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.addAttachment(ComposeMessageActivity.java:2544)
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168):     at com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.handleSendIntent(ComposeMessageActivity.java:2521)
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168):     at com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.initialize(ComposeMessageActivity.java:1703)
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168):     at com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.onCreate(ComposeMessageActivity.java:1633)
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-20 09:15:58.364: ERROR/Mms/media(168):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Maybe you should pass an uri of the form `file:///sdcard/Video0006.mp4`.

Comment: The thing is when I try using

sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(uri)));

It tells me to change uri into an URI instead of a String, when I do that it tells to change the Uri into a String... I don't know what I should do about that.

Comment: What if there will no sdcard?

Comment: @kadik then the file will not be stored on an SD card, but the URI will still be of the same **form**... `file://[partition]/path/to/file`

Answer (score 120):

You can also try this:

```java
Uri.fromFile(new File(your image path));
```

Comment: Can you see what's wrong this code  [ [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44447813/7004388) ] . I'm stuck here. Please guide me.

Comment: As how we get and save files changed with API 24, this is the simplest way to get an URI from a file taken using FileManagers.

Answer (score 9):

#### This worked for me

```
val uri:Uri =  File(path).toUri()
```

Comment: Is the opposite available get a REAL path from the Uri?

Answer (score 0):

Method to save an bitmap to a file

```
  private fun bitmapToFile(bitmap:Bitmap): Uri {
        // Get the context wrapper
        val wrapper = ContextWrapper(applicationContext)

        // Initialize a new file instance to save bitmap object
        var file = wrapper.getDir("Images",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        file = File(file,"${UUID.randomUUID()}.jpg")

        try{
            // Compress the bitmap and save in jpg format
            val stream:OutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,stream)
            stream.flush()
            stream.close()
        }catch (e:IOException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        // Return the saved bitmap uri
        return Uri.parse(file.absolutePath)
    }
```