# Play a videoview from gallery with any path (internal or external) ANDROID

Tags: java, android

I trying this code :

1- Initialization

```
private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 1;
VideoView video;
```

2- onCreate Methos

```
video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoID);
```

3- onClick (implements OnClickListener)

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.VideoID:
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
        break;
        }
    }
```

4- onActivityResult Method

```
if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                video.setVideoURI(uri);
                video.requestFocus();
                video.start();
            }
```

OUTPUT on my Galaxy Note 3:
1- as Toast:

```
data: Intent { dat=content://media/external/video/media/8899 (has extras) }
```

2- as Message Dialog:

```
Can't play this video
```

I want to play a videoview from (the gallery or from anywhere) with any path (internal or external path)

Comment: refer my ans for absolute path http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32049962/filenotfound-exception-while-loading-bitmap-images-from-android-gallery/32050040?noredirect=1#comment51999547_32050040

Comment: Check the path URI first and also what type of video you are trying to play..i mean the extension?

Comment: I said in my question OUTPUT look it URI path, and the video extention is mp4