# When using complete URl in Picasso it works but when using String it did not work?

Tags: android, picasso

```
             Picasso.with(this)
            .load(input)
            .into(image);
   Log .e("input url",input);
```

I am getting the half of the URL from another activity using getExtra

```
 String urlid =getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
```

and I am combing the remaining Url with the half I received.

String input = half URL + urlid; (URL I received)
To check my URL I am using

```
       Log .e("input url",input);
```

Which shows my complete URL and is correct.
But I am getting the error message as

```
   SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

Any help or suggestions.

Comment: {
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 57,
            "topicId": 1,
            "resType": "Mind Maps",
            "resLink": "upload/1/air water & weather.tif",
            "resName": "Air Water and Weather",
            "dateCreated": "2015-10-06T10:40:37Z",
            "topicName": "Air Water Weather",
            "syllabus": "CBSE",
            "grade": "5",
            "subject": "Science",
  
      
       
         
        },@DhavalPatel

Comment: Check that the URL is indeed an image, and not a HTML file. 

check the first few bytes to make sure it is a PNG, XML, JPG, whatever.

Comment: Try this.. `String input = half URL +"/" +urlid;` Add "/" between half url and urlId.

Comment: No did not work @DhavalPatel

Comment: try to change this to getApllicationContext() in picasso

Comment: @saurabhgupta  my URL did not end with .jpg or png it is like this "https://www.example****.com/funlearn/downloadFile?id=27"

Comment: @saurabhgupta no did not work after changing to getApllicationContext();

Comment: Try changing your string path in URI. Refer this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709087/turning-a-string-into-a-uri-android

Comment: can you explain it briefly @SabihAhmed

Comment: Try this : Uri pathURI = Uri.parse("your full concatenated path here"); Picasso.with(this)
            .load(pathURI)
            .into(image);

Comment: still getting blank screen with this error  SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null@SabihAhmed

Comment: @ShwetabhSingh refer this link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559736/android-skimagedecoderfactory-returned-null-error